# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver after checking that connector is in classpath

Tags: java, mysql-connector

I found the solution, and this question was in fact a duplicate, but of a completely different question. If you have a similar problem, check out - [ant, jar files, and Class-Path oh my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190646/ant-jar-files-and-class-path-oh-my)

First:

I have read other posts with the same title (i think all of them). I do know that i need to include mysql-connector-java in classpath, and i am sure i have done this.

Also, i am not asking about suggestions for other tools.

Now, I have the following within the code:

```
        System.out.println(System.getenv("CLASSPATH"));
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

The output is:

```
/home/volodya/OtherPeople/00insert/java/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I can do:

```
$ ls -l $CLASSPATH
-rw-r--r-- 1 volodya volodya 972009 Jun 19 22:26 /home/volodya/OtherPeople/00insert/java/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar
```

I can do:

```
$ java -cp lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar -jar dist/memorial.jar
```

To answer the question about the location of the console:

```
$ ls -l lib/
total 952
-rw-r--r-- 1 volodya volodya 972009 Jun 19 22:26 mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar
```

But it produces exactly the same output. I am very close to unzipping the jar and just putting all the .class files within my own.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson How is this question remotely similar to the one it now links to? Did you read it before you marked it?

Comment: Did **you** read the **accepted answer**, if you did, you would know why what you are doing is incorrect. It is spelled out completely for you if you read for comprehension.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson "In your case you're using an IDE." Where did i even hint at that?

Comment: every `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` without exception is caused by the exact same thing, the class that is being searched for is not on the classpath. **Regardless of what you think you have done and its correctness, the fact renames the JVM can not find the specified class*** this is no mystery.

Comment: Read the very **first sentence** of the accepted answer **for comprehension**, that means read just that sentence and stop and try and comprehend what it says in its entirety without assuming you already think you know what it means.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson "The CLASSPATH environment variable is only used by the java.exe command and even then only when used without any of the -cp, -classpath, -jar arguments." So when i say that i ran `$ java -cp lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar -jar dist/memorial.jar` it clearly takes that out of any picture, since i'm providing it inside -cp. Like i have said, i have read existing answers

Comment: @JarrodRoberson "every java.lang.ClassNotFoundException without exception is caused by the exact same thing". 99% of the posts here ask that same question "What have i done wrong"

Comment: and they answer is you have not put the required class on the classpath because those 99% of the people do not read to understand what they are doing, they just want someone to spoon feed them a solution that is highly localized and most likely a PEBKAC, hence the flood of duplicates. That is what a duplicate is, the same question with the same solution/answer; asked in a different manner or slightly different details does not make it a **not** a duplicate.

Comment: @Volodya What is current location of console? Are you sure that it contains `lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar`?

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getenv("CLASSPATH"));` is an invalid test or proof of anything because it is **not** used when over ridden at the command line with `-cp/-classpath` or `-jar` so you are confused on what you are trying to prove or test to begin with. I doubt that the `.jar` is where you are telling it to look, and you are not including the existing classpath so it will be the **only** thing on the classpath if you finally get the location correct. All solutions from all the duplicates.

Comment: @Pshemo Please see the edit

Comment: if you used a tool like Maven to manage dependencies automatically you would not have these types of **highly localized** human errors.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Please see the edit